# How do I make an element filter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a state in which the selected filters are written:

```
 state = {
    filters: [],
  };
```

There's a list of items:

```
const json = [
    {action : true, new : true, name : 'Морський'},
    {action : true, new : false, name : 'Дольче Віта' },
    {action : false, new : false, name : 'Спекотний сезон' },
    {action : false, new : true, name : 'Уікенд' },
]
```

How do I filter items by selected filters? A state with filters can look like this: `filters ["new", "action"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
const result = json.filter(x => filters.every(y => x[y]));
```

```js
const filters = ["new", "action"];
const json = [
  { action: true, new: true, name: "Морський" },
  { action: true, new: false, name: "Дольче Віта" },
  { action: false, new: false, name: "Спекотний сезон" },
  { action: false, new: true, name: "Уікенд" }
];

const result = json.filter(x => filters.every(y => x[y]));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Its amazing! I have invented this: 

    `const arr = []

    json.forEach(element => {
      keys.forEach(key => {
        if(element[key]) {
          arr.push(element)
        }
      })
    });`

But, its not good solution.